# Can I animate an element to only display once it reaches a certain place on the screen?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate some elements and it doesn't look right. I want one element to be hidden until it slides past a certain place on the screen.

I have two images:

```
<img src='bg.png' />
<img src='line.png' id='line'/>
```

And here's the animation code:

```
@keyframes line{
from   {right: -900px;}
to  {right: 0;}
}

#line{
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
animation-name: line;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

What's happening is that the 'line' is visible on the screen, then it animates. What I'd like to do is keep the 'line' hidden until it reaches the right edge of the background image, which is 900px wide.

Comment: Set this `right: -900px;` prop in your default `#line{` rule. No need for `from`, and `-webkit-` is bad.

Comment: That's close. Is there any way to make everything outside the 'bg.png' image invisible? I tried using overflow - hidden on the image but that didn't work. Thanks for the heads up on webkit.